# Typescript - enforce collection contain only 2 types

Tags: typescript

I have a `Product` interface that has property `items` which is a collection that should accept only 2 types of items: `ServiceTypeOne` and `ServiceTypeTwo`.

This is what i came up with but i am not sure if this is the proper way to do it?

```
export interface Product{
   ...
   items: ProductItem<AcceptedServices>[];
   ...
}

export interface ProductItem<T extends AcceptedServices>{
   item:T;
   quantity:number;
}

export type AcceptedServices = ServiceTypeOne | ServiceTypeTwo;
```

Questions:

1. Is there some better way that i'm missing?
2. At later stage when i'll be iterating over `Product.items` i will want to check particular type of the item (if its underlying type is `ServiceTypeOne` or `ServiceTypeTwo` and based on type run some particular methods for that type). How to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there's no point to use generics in `ProductItem` you can define it as:

```
export interface ProductItem {
    item: AcceptedServices;
    quantity: number;
}
```

> I will want to check particular type of the item

You can define custom [type guards](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
type ServiceTypeOne = { type: 'one' };
type ServiceTypeTwo = { type: 'two' };

export interface Product {
    items: ProductItem[];
}

export interface ProductItem {
    item: AcceptedServices;
    quantity: number;
}

export type AcceptedServices = ServiceTypeOne | ServiceTypeTwo;

function isServiceTypeOne(item: AcceptedServices): item is ServiceTypeOne {
    return item.type === 'one';
}

function isServiceTypeTwo(item: AcceptedServices): item is ServiceTypeTwo {
    return item.type === 'two';
}

declare const product: Product;

for (const productItem of product.items) {
    if (isServiceTypeOne(productItem.item)) {
        // productItem.item is of type ServiceTypeOne
    }
}
```

Comment: The only reason to use generics was to indicate accepted types on the interface level. I've seen that somewhere in docs and liked the idea. / This with type guards is great. Thanks!